# Execute React Test cases on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to build a React Application where the user will be given a code snippet and asked to solve it.

For this, I am not sure how to proceed with the execution of test cases. I am using enzyme

**My Question is**

How to run the test case in the command line on button click in the browser? Any sample is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#events and https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events should give you a starting point